# Missing ID for GTM with RapidWeaver Stacks website

Tags: stack, google-tag-manager, rapidweaver

I'm a total novice when it comes to coding, so I've build my website in RapidWeaver and I'm happy with the result. But when I try to track clicks on my website I run into a problem with a missing ID. Is there any way that I will still be able to track clicks on my website?

I've tried to look at other answers to this, but it all involves a lot of code and I'm so very bad at that.

Comment: Where are you getting the error and what how does the error read exactly?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but when I wanna track clicks on specific bottons for example I first make an "all click"-trigger, then I am suppose be able to go to my website (in preview mode in GTM) and click anywhere and then afterwards look under "variables" to get a specific click ID, that can be used for tagging in GTM. But when I look under variables the only thing that shows up under variables is "". Nothing more.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, you're setting up your tags as this example shows? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en